# Calling jquery dialog from within an ajax generated php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```js
// functions for dialog form....
$(function() {
  var dialog, form, allFields

  // add new dialog
  dialog = $("#frm_Add").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Save": addNewIMTE,
      Cancel: function() {
        dialog.dialog("close");
      }

    },
    close: function() {
      //form[ 0 ].reset();
      // allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
  });

  form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  $("#AddNewItem").button().on("click", function() {
    dialog.dialog("open");
  });
});

// end add new dialog

$(function() {

  // add edit dialog
  var dialogEdit, formEdit, allFieldsEdit
  dialogEdit = $("#dialog-EditForm").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Save": addNewIMTE,
      Cancel: function() {
        dialogEdit.dialog("close");
      }
    },
    close: function() {
      //formEdit[ 0 ].reset();
      //allFieldsEdit.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
  });

  formEdit = dialogEdit.find("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  // $(document).on("click","a#editME",function(){
  // $("a#editME").click(function(){ 
  //      dialogEdit.dialog( "open" );
  // }); 

  $(document).on("click", "#editME", function() {
    dialogEdit.dialog("open");
  });




});


function addNewIMTE() {
  var valid = true;
  allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
  //valid = valid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
  //valid = valid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
  //valid = valid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );
  //valid = valid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, //0-9, underscores, spaces and must begin with a letter." );
  //valid = valid && checkRegexp( email, emailRegex, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
  if (valid) {
    //call save function - saveIMTE()
    //alert('you pressed me');
    saveNewIMTEData();
    dialog.dialog("close");
  }
  return valid;
}
```

```html
<?php session_start();?>

<!DOCTYPE>

<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <title>DJ Inspection</title>

  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pos.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/print.css" media="print" />
  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./scripts/jquery-ui-themes-1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/css01.css" type="text/css" />

  <script src=./scripts/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js></script>
  <script src=./scripts/jquery/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js></script>
  <script src=./scripts/dialogFrms.js></script>

  <script src="./scripts/rpt001.js"></script>
  <script src="./scripts/jquery.printPage.js"></script>

  <script src="./scripts/jquery.printPage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      getStockList("1", "");

    });


    $(function() {
      $("#calDate").datepicker();
    });

    $(function() {
      $("#calDue").datepicker();
    });
  </script>


</head>

<?php date_default_timezone_set( 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'); 
require_once( "common.php"); 
$connection=o penMaintData(); 
$sqlCat="select ID,Description from imtecat" ; 
$rsCat=$ connection->query($sqlCat); 
$rowsCat = $rsCat->num_rows; 
$sqlLocation = "select id,description from location"; 
$rsLocation = $connection->query($sqlLocation); 
$rowsLocation = $rsLocation->num_rows; 
$sqlPIC = "select ID,Name from personnel"; 
$rsPIC = $connection->query($sqlPIC);
$rowsPIC = $rsPIC->num_rows; 
$sqlVendor = "select id,CalVendor from calvendor"; $rsVendor = $connection->query($sqlVendor); $rowsVendor = $rsVendor->num_rows; $sqlPeriod = "select ID,Period from inspperiod"; $rsPeriod = $connection->query($sqlPeriod);
$rowsPeriod = $rsPeriod->num_rows; mysqli_close($connection); ?>

<body>


  <img src="/djapps/img/dj logo red.png" alt="djlogo">

  <div id='breadcrumb'>
  </div>

  <div id=stklistheader>

    <table border=0 class='hello' width=0%>
      <tr>

        <td>
          <a href="javascript:" onclick=" getStockList('','');">
            <div id="filterButton"></div>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>

          <!--<a class="btnPrint" href='/DJApps/print01.html'>Print!</a>
      -->
        </td>

        <td>
          <button id="AddNewItem">Create New Item</button>

          <a href="#" id="editME">Edit</a">
            <div id="FilterType"></div>
              </td></tr>
            </table>
  
          <table>
            <tr>   
              <td>
                Search
              </td>
              <td>
                <input name="cSearchThis" id='cSearchThis' type="text" size="50" maxlength="80"/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
             </table>
  </div>  
  
  <div id=stklistheader1>
  
  </div>  
  
  <div id="placeStkList"></div>
   
 </div>
 
</table>

</div>

<div id="placeRightChildInfo">
 fdfdd
</div>

<?php include 'dialogAddNew.php'?>
<?php include 'dialogEdit.php'?>
  
 
</body>

<script>
 
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btnPrint").printPage();
 });
 
 document.getElementById("filterButton").innerHTML = "Alarm Scan"; 
 
 $( "#cSearchThis" ).keyup(function( event ) {
  getStockList("1","");
 });
 
 

     $(".myclass tr").click(function(){
       window.location = "example.html";
     });
 
</script>



</html>


  
    
<!-- this is ajaxListStk01- called by ajax-->
  
    <?php
 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
 require_once "/JSON.php";
 
  
 $param0    = trim(strip_tags((isset($_GET['str1']) && $_GET['str1'] != '') ? $_GET['str1'] : ''));
 $param1    = trim(strip_tags((isset($_GET['sid']) && $_GET['sid'] != '') ? $_GET['sid'] : ''));
 
 $jsonArray = json_decode($param0,'true');
 $noItems   = sizeof($jsonArray["sStkList"])-1;    
 $QtyItem   = $noItems+1;
 
 switch(json_last_error())
 {
  case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
  // echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
  break;
  case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
  // echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
  break;
  case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
  // echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
  break;
  case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
  //    echo ' - No errors';
  break;
 }
 
 require_once("common.php");
 
 $whatElse = $jsonArray["sStkList"][0]["flag"];
 $SearchThis = $jsonArray["sStkList"][0]["descrip"];
 $SortBy = $jsonArray["sStkList"][0]["sortBy"];
 
 //$orderStr = $SortBy;
 
 echo "Sorted By: ".$SortBy;
 
 $connection = openMaintData();
 
 //$now = date("Y-m-d");
 $now = time(); // or your date as well
 
 $certPath = "/certRep/";
 $imgPath = "/images/";
 $iconPath = "/icons/";
 
 if($whatElse == "A"){
  $activeStr  = " DATEDIFF(imtemaster.CalDue, NOW()) <= 30 and ";
  $orderStr = " imtemaster.CalDue ASC";
  $whatElse = "FILTERED ";
 }else{
  $activeStr  = "";
  $orderStr = "imtemaster.Description ASC";
  $whatElse = "ALL";
 }
 
 if($SortBy <> ""){
  $activeStr  = "";
  $orderStr = $SortBy;
  $whatElse = "SORTED";
 }
 
 echo "** ".$SearchThis.' - '.$whatElse.' - '.$activeStr;
 
 
 
 $sqlStr = "SELECT
 imtemaster.id,
 imtemaster.catID,
 imtemaster.description,
 imtemaster.serialno,
 imtemaster.Brand,
 imtemaster.Model,
 imtemaster.Specs,
 imtemaster.CalDate,
 imtemaster.CalDue,
 imtemaster.CalPeriod,
 imtemaster.CalBy,
 imtemaster.CertRef,
 imtemaster.Location,
 imtemaster.PIC,
 imtemaster.Status,
 imtemaster.Remarks,
 imtecat.Description,
 inspperiod.Period,
 calvendor.CalVendor,
 personnel.Name,
 status.description,
 Location.description,
 imtemaster.image
 FROM imtemaster 
 INNER JOIN imtecat ON imtecat.ID = imtemaster.catID 
 LEFT JOIN inspperiod ON inspperiod.ID = imtemaster.CalPeriod
 LEFT JOIN calvendor ON calvendor.id = imtemaster.CalBy
 LEFT JOIN status ON status.id = imtemaster.Status
 LEFT JOIN Location ON Location.id = imtemaster.Location
 LEFT JOIN personnel ON personnel.ID = imtemaster.PIC 
 where ".$activeStr."
 (imtemaster.description LIKE '%".$SearchThis."%' || imtemaster.Brand LIKE '%".$SearchThis."%'
 || imtemaster.serialno LIKE '%".$SearchThis."%'
 || imtemaster.ID LIKE '%".$SearchThis."%'
 || imtemaster.Specs LIKE '%".$SearchThis."%'
 || imtemaster.Model LIKE '%".$SearchThis."%'
 || imtemaster.Brand LIKE '%".$SearchThis."%'
 || imtemaster.CertRef LIKE '%".$SearchThis."%'
 || personnel.Name LIKE '%".$SearchThis."%'
 || imtecat.Description LIKE '%".$SearchThis."%'
 || Location.Description LIKE '%".$SearchThis."%'
 || calvendor.CalVendor LIKE '%".$SearchThis."%'
 || status.description LIKE '%".$SearchThis."%'
 || imtemaster.Remarks LIKE '%".$SearchThis."%'
 || imtemaster.Remarks LIKE '%".$SearchThis."%')
 order by ".$orderStr; 
 
 // and
 //(imtemaster.Status != 2)
 // echo $sqlStr;
 
 $rsInv = $connection->query($sqlStr); 
 
 $rowsInv = $rsInv->num_rows;
 
 echo "No of IMTE found: ".$rowsInv;
 
 echo '<a href="#" id="itemEdit">Edit</a">';
 
 
 if ($rowsInv > 0) {
  
  echo '<div class="scrollableContainer">
  <div class="scrollingArea">
  
  <table class="imte fixHeader">
  <thead>
  
  <tr id="myclass" bgcolor="#CC99FF">
  
  <th><div class="ID">
  <a href="#" onClick="getStockList(\'1\',\' imtemaster.id ASC\');">ID</a></div></th>
  
  
  <th><div class="Status">
  <a href="#" onClick="getStockList(\'1\',\' status.description ASC\');">Status</a></div></th>
  <th><div class="Cat">
  <a href="#" onClick="getStockList(\'1\',\' imtecat.Description ASC\');">Type</a></div></th>
  
  <th><div class="Descrip">
  <a href="#" onClick="getStockList(\'1\',\' imtemaster.Description ASC\');">Description</a></div></th>
  
  <th><div class="SNo">
  <a href="#" onClick="getStockList(\'1\',\' imtemaster.serialno\');">Serial No</a></div></th>
  
  <th><div class="Per">
  <a href="#" onClick="getStockList(\'1\',\' inspperiod.Period ASC\');">Period</a></div></th>
  
  <th><div class="CalOn">
     <a href="#" onClick="getStockList(\'1\',\' imtemaster.CalDate ASC\');">Cal On</a></div></th>
 
  <th><div class="CalDue">
  <a href="#" onClick="getStockList(\'1\',\' imtemaster.CalDue ASC\');">Due</a></div></th>
  
  <th><div class="Days2Exp">Exp (Days)</div></th>
  
  <th><div class="Loc">
  <a href="#" onClick="getStockList(\'1\',\' Location.description ASC\');">Loc</a></div></th>
 
  <th><div class="CalBy">
  <a href="#" onClick="getStockList(\'1\',\' calvendor.CalVendor ASC\');">Cal By</a></div></th>
   
  <th><div class="Remarks">Remarks</div></th>
  <th><div class="Edit">Action</div></th>
  <th><div class="Image">Img</div></th>
  <th><div class="PDF">Cert</div></th>
  <th><div class="Excel">Excel</div></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>';
  
  $i = 0;

  while ($rowsInv=mysqli_fetch_row($rsInv))
  {
   $id               = $rowsInv[0];
   $catID            = $rowsInv[1];
   $description      = $rowsInv[2];
   $serialno         = $rowsInv[3];
   $Brand            = $rowsInv[4];
   $Model            = $rowsInv[5];
   $Specs            = $rowsInv[6];
   $CalDate          = $rowsInv[7];
   $CalDue           = $rowsInv[8];
   $CalPeriod        = $rowsInv[9];
   $CalByID           = $rowsInv[10];
   $CertRef          = $rowsInv[11];
   $Location         = $rowsInv[12];
   $PIC              = $rowsInv[13];
   $Remarks          = $rowsInv[15];
   $CatDescp         = $rowsInv[16];
   $Period           = $rowsInv[17];
   $CalBy            = $rowsInv[18];
   $PIC              = $rowsInv[19];
   $Status           = $rowsInv[20];
   $WhereIsIt        = $rowsInv[21];
   $StatusID        = $rowsInv[14];
   $image        = $rowsInv[22];
   
   $i = $i + 1;
   
   if($i % 2 ==0)
   
   {
    $bgcolor='#FFFFFF';
    }else{
    $bgcolor='#E9E9E9';
   }
   
   // $offset = $Period; 
   // $now = time();
   // $days2expiry = floor((strtotime(date('Y-m-d', 
   // strtotime("+$offset months-1 day", //strtotime($CalDate))))-$now)/(60*60*24));

   $datediff =strtotime($CalDue)-$now;
   $days2expiry = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
   
   if ($days2expiry <= 30 ){
    $bgcolor='FFAA7F';
   };
   
   if ($days2expiry > 0 and $days2expiry <= 30  ) {
    $bgcolor='FFCC99';
   };
      
   if ($days2expiry <= 0 ){
    $bgcolor= 'red';
   };
   
   if ($Status == 7 ){
    $bgcolor='FFAA7F';
   }
   
   //echo '<td ><div>'.$i.'</div></td>';   
   // echo '<td ><div>'.$CatDescp.'-'.trim($description).'-'.trim($Brand).'-'.trim($Model).'-'.trim($Specs).'</div></td>';
   //echo '<td><div>'.$CalDate.'</div></td>';
   //echo '<td><div>'.$CalDue.'</div></td>';
   //echo '<td><div>'.$Period.'</div></td>';
   //echo '<td><div>'.$CalBy.'</div></td>';
   //echo '<td><div>'.$CertRef.'</div></td>';
   //echo '<td><div>'.$PIC.'</div></td>';
   //echo '<td><div>'.$WhereIsIt.'</div></td>';
   
   //echo '<td><div><a id="create-newIMTE">Edit</a></div></td>';
   
   echo '<tr color='.$bgcolor.'>';
   
   echo '<td ><div class="ID">
   <a id="itemEdit" href="#">'.$id.'</a>
   </div></td>';
   
   echo '<td ><div class="Status">'.$Status.'('.trim($StatusID).')'.'</div></td>';
   echo '<td ><div  class="Cat">'.$CatDescp.'('.trim($catID).')'.'</div></td>';
   echo '<td ><div  class="Descrip">'.trim($description).'-'.trim($Brand).'-'.trim($Model).'-'.trim($Specs).'</div></td>';
   echo '<td><div class="SNo">'.$serialno.'</div></td>';
   echo '<td><div class="Per">'.$Period.'</div></td>';
   echo '<td><div class="CalOn">'.$CalDate.'</div></td>';
   echo '<td><div class="CalDue">'.$CalDue.'</div></td>';
   echo '<td ><div class="Days2Exp">'.(float)$days2expiry.'</div></td>';
   echo '<td><div   class="Loc">'.$WhereIsIt.'('.trim($Location).')'.'</div></td>';
   echo '<td><div   class="CalBy">'.$CalBy.'-('.$CalByID.')'.'</div></td>';
   echo '<td><div  class="Remarks">'.$Remarks.'</div></td>';
   echo '<td><div  class="Edit"><a onClick="yourFunction(); return false;" href="fallback.html">One Way</a>';
   
   
   //echo '<td><div class="Image"><a href="'.$imgPath.'/'.$id.'.png" target="_blank">Pic</a></div></td>';
   /*
   echo '
   <td>
   <div class="Image">
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($image) .'" />
   </div>
   </td>';
   */

   if ( !empty( $image ) ) {
   echo '<td><div  class="Img"><a href="'.$imgPath.'/'.$id.'.png" target="_blank"><img src="'.$imgPath.'/'.$id.'.png" alt="Pic" title="Click to view" border="0" width="20px" height="20px" hspace="10px" /></a></div></td></a>';
   
   }else{
   
   echo '<td><div  class="Img"><a href="'.$imgPath.'/na.png" target="_blank"><img src="'.$imgPath.'/na.png" alt="Pic" title="Click to view" border="0" width="20px" height="20px" hspace="10px" /></a></div></td></a>';
   
   }
   
   echo '<td><div  class="PDF"><a href="'.$certPath.'/'.$id.'.pdf" target="_blank">
   <img src="'.$iconPath.'pdf.png" alt="PDF" title="Click to view" border="0" width="20px" height="20px" hspace="10px" />cert</a></div></td>';
   echo '<td><div  class="Excel"><a href="'.$certPath.'/'.$id.'.xlsx">IHCert</a></div></td>';
   
   //<a href="#" id="create-newIMTE">Edit</a></div></td>';
   //<a href='javascript:myFunction()'> Click Me! <a/>
  };
  
 }
 
 echo '<div id="register"></div>';
 
 echo '</tbody></table>';
 
  
 
 echo '</div>';
 echo '</div>';
 
 
 
 
?>
```

I have search similar questions but am not able to find the solution to my problem.

I am trying to use jquery dialog from a hyper link generated through ajax.
The javascripts are all ran from the first page that called the ajax. 
When I click on the hyper link, there is no response but when I put the same hyperlink on the first page, it works.

This is generated by ajax:
    '.$id.'

The javascript is ran when the program initialized:

```
$("a#editME").click(function(){ 
dialogEdit.dialog( "open" );
```

Could someone help?

Thanks

[ajax generated table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5v1M.png)

Comment: Sorry the code generated by ajax is:                                                                                                                       <a id="itemEdit" href="#">'.$id.'</a>

Comment: It is still not working... should I place the javascript that ready the dialog scripts inside the ajax generated php file?

Comment: can you please put the code snippet out here ?

Comment: good if you post browser rendered `html` or some more detailed code here..

Comment: This has been solved - using the code provided by Sandeep and Rao. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this

```
$(document).on("click","a#editME",function(){
    dialogEdit.dialog( "open" );
})
```

Comment: actually your html "<a id="itemEdit" href="#">'.$id.'</a>" is being generated dynamically so you should bind or delegate your html if require to perform any action like click or change

Comment: sandeep, sorry I don't understand what you mean by bind or delegate. Could you please explain?

Comment: Rao, yes did that and still not working. Should I put out more code snippets?

Comment: when you dynamically generate the any html element then we have to bind it with it if need to trigger any event just like you are creating "<a>" dynamically then if you need to perform some click option on it then you need to bind the specific element using some jquery method like bind,on and once you are done you can unbind using unbind,off method see more out here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp

Comment: I am not sure how to present the codes to you... there are inserted above.

Comment: Guys, thanks I got it already. Yep using the code you gave me - actually it was my mistake also I had named the hyperlink ID and the script calling ID wrongly. So there, it works and thanks for the explanation on binding, Sandeep. And Rao thanks also. Cheers

Comment: @ClementTKY if you find the answer then please accept it .. thanks

Comment: Sandeep, if you excuse my ignorance, how do I proceed to accept the answer? Do I just leave it or do I have to click on something...?

Comment: @ClementTKY see my answer explanation where you will find a tick bar just click on it